# Chocolatey - Python - Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: chocolatey

I installed Python using Chocolatey:

```
choco install python3
```

I did this in an administrative PowerShell prompt. The results *seem* successful enough:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco install python3 --force
Installing the following packages:
python3
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.

python3 v3.6.0 (forced)
The package python3 wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider setting
 'allowGlobalConfirmation'. Run 'choco feature -h' for more details.
Do you want to run the script?
 1) yes
 2) no
 3) print
yes
 Downloading python3 64 bit
   from 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/python-3.6.0-amd64.exe'
 Hashes match.
 Installing python3...
 python3 has been installed.
 Installed to 'C:\Python36'
 The install of python3 was successful.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 package(s). 0 package(s) failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

However, I don't seem to have Python:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> python
The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
```

So...maybe it's installed, but not in my PATH? Is there some way for me to know where it installed to?

Comment: You need to add `C:\Python36;C:\Python36\bin` to your `PATH`, and then restart the terminal or use `refreshenv`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows you can't normally just install something and immediately use it on the command line without closing and reopening your command shell.

Chocolatey however comes with a command you can run called "refresh environment", or `refreshenv` for short. Typically if the PATH gets updated, Chocolatey reminds you to run `refreshenv` to update your shell.

This allows you to immediately take advantage of newly installed apps.

Here's an annotated example of this:

[image: Shows Upgrades / PATH changes / refreshenv]

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `refreshenv`!

Comment: When I tried it, `refreshenv` didn't work for me on Windows 10, installing Python - 'python'  could not be found. 'python' started when invoked in a newly opened PowerShell window.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - by default refreshenv won't work in PowerShell, you must have the PowerShell profile for Chocolatey set up. See https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting#refreshenv-has-no-effect

Comment: Back in 2021, there seems to be problems installing Python3.9 in choco. It wont, but creates a link to the MS Store when `python` from PS. In `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib` there is python that contains nupkg and nuspec but not more after choco install python. I get also errors:  - python3 (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

It's installed here as you can see from the installation log:

```
'C:\Python36'
```

Comment: Thanks, I failed to read the output due to a combination of frustration, disillusionment and pessimism.